# how to install bprojection addon

Tags: add-on

here is the link for the addon:

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/bprojection

But I don't understand how to install this, apart from installing zip files as I've done that before.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Open this [link](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-extensions/contrib/py/scripts/addons/space_view3d_paint_bprojection.py)
2. Select all text and open any text editor then paste it in it.
3. Save it with this name `space_view3d_paint_bprojection.py` in Blender's add-ons folder:
   Example for Linux:

`/home/userA/.blender/2.78/scripts/addons/`

Example for Windows:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons
```

Example for macOS:

```
/Users/%username%/blender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.78/scripts/addons
```

4. Open *User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) and under *Add-ons*, click *Install from File*. Then navigate to the file you downloaded and select it.

[image]

3. It should now appear in the window and you can tick the checkbox in the upper right to enable it.

[image]

If you would like to have the add-on enabled every time you start Blender, click *Save User Settings* at the bottom.